# how to Campare input string with database object

Tags: django

Here when I give input to feature_name as `newFeature`, it gives me folder found but when I give `newFeature123`, it gives me folder not found

In FeatureCache table these two are `newFeature123` and `newFeature`. These folder name are present but its match with newFeature but not with newFeature123.

*views.py:*

```
def passReviewerProjFeature(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        feature_name = request.POST['tcrsearch_id']
        project_id = request.POST['tcrproject_id']
        featureObjectarray=FeatureCache.objects.filter(project=project_id)
        for object in featureObjectarray:
               print object.name
               if feature_name not in str(object.name):
                   print feature_name
                   print "not Present"
                   return render(request,'index.html',{'errmsg':"Folder Not Found"})
               else:
                   return render(request,'index.html',{'errmsg':"Folder Found"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups) in django queryset.

Basically `contains` and `icontains` may be what you are looking for:

`FeatureCache.objects.filter(project__icontains=feature_name, project__exact=project_id)`

which will do case insensitive lookup. Something like this:

```
featureObjectarray=FeatureCache.objects.filter(project__icontains=feature_name, project__exact=project_id)
if featureObjectarray.exists():
  return render(request,'index.html',{'errmsg':"Folder Found"})
else:
  print feature_name
  print "not Present"
  return render(request,'index.html',{'errmsg':"Folder Not Found"})
```